# Cannot login to codename one from netbeans or eclipse

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

I am trying to log in to send an android build, but when i try to log in it says that username or password isnt like something they have in file, although i am entering the correct info.

Comment: Can you share your code and the error message as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using an old version of the Codename One plugin. I would recommend using maven and avoiding the plugin to stay up to date. Logging in with new versions works by launching your web browser. If you can login from the browser then you're logged in with the build process.